# Controlling Brushless Motor ESC Remotely

Tags: arduino, motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, potentiometer

[image: The ESC in question]

I currently have this https://a.co/d/hen7RIb brushless motor ESC from Amazon. I need this to accept a different input than the potentiometer. Right now for remote control we have this ESC connected to a relay with it's potentiometer on high, so when a HIGH value is sent to the relay the motor turns to max and the expected result for a LOW input. I want more control than this and want to remotely send values to fully control the motor.

I am unsure of how to do this when it already has a potentiometer attached. Other ESC's I've seen people control with Arduino do not have the potentiometer attached. It appears that I would need to unsolder this potentiometer and attach a PWM pin to where the output pin of the potentiometer was. I don't know if this would work however, as the operating voltages of my Arudino and this ESC are different, so I don't know if sending an analogWrite(1023) would have the expected result. I'm unsure how to proceed with the remote modification of this ESC

Comment: COM - common ...

Comment: Ah thank you jsotola, so not for communication then? Would the only route be unsoldering the potentiometer? Also, would this input need to be 0-1023 instead of 0-180, or is this potentiometer likely already reconfigured to be 0-180 for brushless control?

Comment: this site is not a forum ... please do not add question in a comment ... edit your question at top of this page and delete the comment

Comment: Edit the question for additional queries, please.

Comment: The more I think about it (digital pot, optocoupler, PWM etc), the lesser I believe in it. How much noise does that ESC produce, that can interfere with digital signals? Can the ESC be ok with PWM? Is isolation between Arduino and ESC necessary? || *Maybe you should look at alternatives, an ESC that natively can be Arduino controlled.*

Comment: MiNiMe, I know that most ESC's are ok with PWM, as most are controllable as if they were servo's from a PWM pin that can take a potentiometer mapped as a servo, or any other input mapped 0-180. The issue is my team decided not to purchase one of those and go with this one, which as potentiometer pre-attached and I am unsure if this one can act as a standard one once the pot is removed